# To what degree is volume correlated with price impact?

Tags: trading, market-microstructure, exchange, volume, market-impact

There is question from 2017 [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34224/relation-between-price-changes-and-trading-volume-market-impact) but the answer given doesn't really go into any detail.

How correlated is volume with price impact? Especially with regard to wash trading; For example, wash trading is extremely prevalent in crypto markets and yet, despite this, one can still a clear correlation between volume and price impact.

Is there a nice formula that can break down the relationship?

Comment: Related topics: volume/dollar bars, net volume.

Comment: It is a classic observation in many markets that there is a relation between volume and the absolute value of the price change. See for example this review article by Karpoff 1987 https://www.jstor.org/stable/2330874?seq=1

Answer (score 3):

Market impact corresponds to price moves due to the intensity of trading in one direction. As you mention: when a market participant trades in size in one direction, the price usually follows.

They are two reasons:

1. the first one is **informational**: the trader is right to buy (or sell), he or she understood the price will go up (or down). Hence in this case, a relation with volume is not needed: the price will move.
2. the second one is **mechanical**: it is the one you mention. The pressure of the buying flow moves the price. In such a case the relation between the traded quantity $Q$ and the price move $\Delta P$ is square root (Bacry, Emmanuel, Adrian Iuga, Matthieu Lasnier, and C-A L. "[Market impacts and the life cycle of investors orders](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.0217.pdf)" Market Microstructure and Liquidity 1, no. 02 (2015)):
   $$\Delta P\propto \sigma\sqrt{Q\over V} + a\,\psi,$$
   where $\sigma$ is the volatility of the specific instrument, $\psi$ its bid-ask spread, and $V$ its traded volume.

JP Bouchaud explains the two effects quite well in his Introduction to Part II. Price Impact: Information Revelation or Self- Fulfilling Prophecies? to Capponi, Agostino, and C-A L, eds. [Machine Learning and Data Sciences for Financial Markets: A Guide to Contemporary Practices](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/machine-learning-and-data-sciences-for-financial-markets/8BB31611662A96D0AB93A8A26E2D0D0A) Cambridge University Press, 2023.